# What are the eigenvalues of the curvature operator on $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, curvature

On page 150 of section 4.5.3 of Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* it is noted that, given an orthonormal basis $X,iX,Y,iY$ for $T_p\mathbb{C}P^2$, the following basis diagonalizes the curvature operator $\mathfrak{R}:\Lambda^2T_p\mathbb{C}P^2 \to \Lambda^2T_p\mathbb{C}P^2  $:

\begin{align*}
&X \wedge iX \pm Y \wedge iY\\
& X \wedge Y \pm iX \wedge iY \\
& X \wedge iY \pm Y \wedge iX
\end{align*}

with eigenvalues lying in $[0,6]$. I have attempted the calculations using the O'Neill formula but get stuck. For example assume $\mathfrak{R}(X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY)=c \left(X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY\right)$. Then:

\begin{align*}
g(\mathfrak{R}(X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY),X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY)&=cg(X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY,X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY)\\ &=2c
\end{align*}

and by the definition of $\mathfrak{R}$:

\begin{align*}
&g(\mathfrak{R}(X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY),X \wedge iX + Y \wedge iY) \\ &=R(X,iX,iX,X)+R(Y,iY,iY,Y)+2R(X,iX,iY,Y) \\ &=\sec(X,iX)+\sec(Y,iY)+2R(X,iX,iY,Y) \\ &=8+2R(X,iX,iY,Y)
\end{align*}

so:

\begin{align*}2c &= 8+2R(X,iX,iY,Y) \\ c&=4+R(X,iX,iY,Y) \end{align*}

At this point I do not know how to proceed. I know of a formula for expanding $R(X,iX,iY,Y)$ in terms of sectional curvatures but it is quite complicated. Alternatively, going back to the O'Neill formula we have:

\begin{align*}R(X,iX,iY,Y)=\overline{R}(\overline{X},\overline{iX},\overline{iY},\overline{Y})+\frac14 \overline{g} ([\overline{iX},\overline{Y} ],[\overline{X},\overline{iY}])-\frac14 \overline{g}([\overline{X},\overline{Y}],[\overline{iX},\overline{iY}]) \end{align*}

where $\overline{R}$ denotes the curvature tensor on $S^5$, $\overline{g}$ denotes the metric on $S^5$, and $\overline{V}$ denotes a horizontal lift. Again, continuing from here seems needlessly complicated.